# Element keeps moving when user creates new review in css

Tags: html, css, styling

I am creating a website in html & css through Django. But I am having some difficulties. Here is my code for the buggy element of the code:

```
detail.html

<div class="contact-info" style="float: right!important; position: sticky!important; margin-right: 25px!important; margin-left: 750px!important; width: 30%!important; height: 50px!important; padding-bottom: 195px!important; margin-top: -2200px!important;">

  <div class="elements" style=" margin-bottom: 200px!important; padding-bottom: 20px!important;">

    <div class="address">
        <span class="icon-map-marker"></span>
        <p> <a style="color:grey!important; border:none!important;" href="{{restraunt.address_link}}">{{restraunt.address}}</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="address" >
        <span class="icon-mobile-phone"></span>
        <p style="color: grey!important; border: none!important;"><a style="color:grey!important; border: none!important;" href="tel:{{restraunt.phone}}" style="color: grey!important;">+{{restraunt.phone|phonenumber}}</a> </p>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
        <span class="icon-link"></span>
        <p><a style="color:grey!important; border: none!important;" href="{{restraunt.website}}">{{restraunt.website}}</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="address">
        <span style="" class="icon-time"></span>
        <p>Mon - Sun, {{restraunt.opening_hour}} - {{restraunt.closing_hour}} <br>
    </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

The code seems to work fine until I enter a new review. Then, the element jumps down and keeps jumping as a new review is added. I don't know how to fix this as I tried `postion: relative`, `postition: absolute` and `position: sticky` but all seem to have failed. I will put some screenshots to explain it better.

Before new Review:

[image]

After a new Review:

[image]

I have been unable to solve this problem for a long time now. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you

Comment: Why do you put the styles inside the HTML tags? This is difficult to read and debug. A seperate stylesheet seems much better.

Comment: @KIKO Software thanks for the reply yes that's a good piece of advice I will take in on board thanks